Fetch data to server that is hosted by Vercel
I'm testing to fetch data from client to server that I host by Vercel.
The code of server is:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)

cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "test"

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    data = request.json['data']
    # print(data)
    return jsonify({'message': f'Received:{data}'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()`

When I host by Vercel the link to the server is https://cc-sqobm4548-tqtcses-projects.vercel.app.
And the code from client that send data to the server is:
<script>
    function submit(){
    data = document.getElementById('data').value
    console.log(data)
    fetch('https://cc-sqobm4548-tqtcses-projects.vercel.app/submit',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({data: data})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.message))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    }
</script>

I have tested when I host the server locally and it responds. I am expecting that the server responds to the API submit, but when I host server on vercel it says fail to fetch. What is wrong and how can I fix that?
